# Pull Tridion Page Metadata Contents

Tags: core-service, 2013

I'm using SDL Tridion version 2013.
Can anyone provide sample code to pull page metadata contents using CoreService?

Comment: There's no 2012 version. Please be more specific in what you want to do. Do you want to read page metadata? If so, through which interface - CoreService, or TOM.NET?

Comment: Apologies. ver 2013. Using CoreService.

Comment: @Rick, welcome to the Tridion community.  Please have a look at http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  It is customary to demonstrate your effort in researching the answer.  Once you do that many of us will be happy to help.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are using Tridion 2011/2013, Page Metadata can be read in several ways.

1. Templates

   `@@Page.Metadata.field@@`
   (Dreamweaver Syntax)

   `ItemFields metaFields = new ItemFields(page.Metadata, page.MetadataSchema);` (TOM.Net)
2. Event System

   `ItemFields metaFields = new ItemFields(page.Metadata, page.MetadataSchema);` (TOM.Net)
3. Core Services

   `PageData page = channel.Read(pageId, new ReadOptions());`

   `XElement xMetadata = XElement.Parse(page.Metadata);`
4. Content Delivery

   `PageMetaFactory metaFactory = new PageMetaFactory(publicationId);`

   `IPageMeta pageMeta = metaFactory.GetMetaByUrl(pageUrl);`

   `CustomMeta customMeta = pageMeta.CustomMeta;`

Comment: ver 2013. Using CoreService.

Comment: The fieldname is PricingPageType. I've tried Page.metadata.Fields.PricingPageType,Metadata.Fields.PricingPageType,Page.Fields.PricingPageType, Page.PricingPageType with no success.

Comment: Try Page.Metadata.PricingPageType

Comment: I usually use the Core Service fields helper when accessing fields and metafields via core service.  Creates a tom-like API.  https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata

Comment: Here's the new link now that this code has been moved from Google Code to GitHub: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Razor Mediator, this can be done fairly easily. I'd created a "[debugging TBB](http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2013/05/14/make-a-debugging-tbb-for-tridion-2011-using-razor-mediator/)" in razor that goes over most all of the properties accessible to you from Razor. If you were looking for a hard example with razor, it'd just be `@Page.Metadata`.

If you aren't using Razor mediator, then I'd like to encourage you to start - simply because it makes a task like this very simple. If for some reason you can't, I'd defer you to the .net-based answers.

Answer (score -1):

first, there is no Tridion version 2012, i think you are talking about 2011 SP1? and you can read page metadata from CoreService and TOM.NET, depending how you want to implement the third  party application. let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Apologies. ver 2013. Using CoreService.

Comment: ok, no problem, for 2013 you can use Coreservice, which is preferred method for integrate your third party application. for coreservice reference: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/ if i am correct give me some score :)